# How to set margin to Image control spark

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, adobe

```
<s:Image id="loader1" top="50" source="@Embed(source='logo.png')"/>
```

the top property doesn't work, how to margin images?

Comment: If the `top` property "doesn't work", the Image is likely inside a container that doesn't support absolute positioning. Perhaps you should show a little more of your code.

Comment: the image is inside a mx:VBox, is there a way to margin images inside a non absolute supported container?, if I set it absolute, I will have to position all the elements, but I just want to margin one element(Image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your image is inside a `VBox` and you want only to pad the Image and not the other components, here are some options:

- Put the Image inside a `Group`: the VBox wil layout the Group vertically and the Image will be positioned 50px from the top of the Group
- Put a `Spacer` between the Image and the component before it and give it a height of 50px.
- If the Image is the first element, you can set `paddingTop="50"` on the VBox.

Side note: you'd better use `s:VGroup` instead of `mx:VBox` since you seem to already use Spark components: it has better performance.